# Convert long html to multiple pages using phantomJS

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, pdf-generation

I have a long html page with 3 equal blocks as shown in image.I need to convert that to pdf as page 1, 2 and 3. Is there some setting that allows me to do that? currently it converts whole html into 1 page.

I am using phantomjs to convert html into pdf.

[image: long html]

`$ phantomjs rasterize.js "http://exampleschools.com/Albury_High_School/1.html" albury.pdf`

Comment: ```$ phantomjs rasterize.js "http://exampleschools.com/Albury_High_School/1.html" albury.pdf "909px*1286px"``` seems to be doing the trick.